# Integrating $\sin^{101}x$

Tags: calculus

I was wondering how to go about in doing this integral

$$ \int^{\pi}_{0} \sin^{101}x \,dx$$

Do I use the Wallis formula or is there something else that I could do?

Comment: With $t = \cos x$, you can turn it into
$$\int_0^\pi \left(1-\cos^2 x \right)^{50} \sin x \,dx \longrightarrow \int_{-1}^1 (1-t^2)^{50} dt$$

Answer (score 5):

Integrate by parts:
\begin{align}
\int\sin^{100}x\sin x\,dx
&=-\sin^{100}x\cos x+100\int\sin^{99}x\cos^2x\,dx\\
&=-\sin^{100}x\cos x+100\int\sin^{99}x\,dx-100\int\sin^{101}x\,dx
\end{align}
Thus, if
$$
I_{n}=\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin^nx\,dx
$$
we have
$$
I_{101}=\Bigl[-\sin^{100}x\cos x\Bigr]_0^{\pi}+100\,I_{99}-100\,I_{101}
$$
which implies
$$
I_{101}=\frac{100}{101}I_{99}
$$
Repeat.

> Continuing in the same way, $\displaystyle I_{101}=\frac{100\cdot98\cdot\ldots\cdot2}{101\cdot 99\cdot\ldots\cdot3}I_1=\frac{2^{101}(50!)^2}{101!}$

Answer (score 4):

$\sin^{101}(x) = \sin^{100}(x)\sin(x) = (1 - \cos^2(x))^{50}\sin(x)$

So set $u = \cos(x)$ in the integration, $du = -\sin(x)dx$

The integrand will be $-(1-u^2)^{50}du$, which is a polynomial.

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

If $I_m=\int_0^\pi\sin^mx\ dx,$

Using [Reduction Formula](http://www.vias.org/calculus/07_trigonometric_functions_05_03.html),

$$I_n=\dfrac{n-1}nI_{n-2}$$

$$I_1=\int_0^\pi\sin x\ dx=?$$